# RxJs 6 DebounceTime operator not working properly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this request that I want to debounce every one second:

```
this.service.doStuff(data)
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(1000),
                distinctUntilChanged()
            )
            .subscribe(data => {
               foo();
            }, () => {
                console.error("server error");
            });
```

DoStuff function:

```
public doStuff(data: any){
        return this.http.post(streetSearch, data).pipe(
            map(res => res.json()));
    }
```

this code is executed from the event `(keyup)` of an `input`. The problem is that whenever I release a key a call get called. Obviously this is not what I wanted.

What I'm trying to achieve is to do the httpCall only when I didn't press a key for, at least, a second (that's why the debounce).

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the expected behavior that you want?

Comment: And where is your http request placed? It might be a good idea to share the doStuff() function with us.

Comment: Working for me as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rambrw

Comment: @enno.void Thank you for the example, but I don't want to use this method (if possible). In the previous version of rxJs I had no problems doing that. But now isn't working and I've no idea why.

Comment: @ngfelixl No idea why you need it but I've added it in the quesiton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this code is executed from the event (keyup) of an input

means that everytime you press a key, then this code is ran.

This means that you make an HTTP call on every key, which is coherent with your current behavior : HTTP calls aren't hot observables, so unless you transform them into one, you won't be able to use debounceTime on it.

What you should do instead is listen to the value changes of your input.

```
myFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  switchMap(value => this.service.doStuff(value)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I think `debounceTime` needs to be before the `switchMap`.

Comment: Not sure about that, but since I haven't tested it, I will listen to you @fridoo !

Comment: Thakn you @trichetriche it helped me quite a lot. I've solved using `fromEvent` instead of formControl tho.